# How to measure distance from moving object using RFID?

Tags: microcontroller, rf, communication, rfid, transmitter

I want to make a project on an anti-collision system using RFID. I'm facing many problems selecting RF reader and tag: the required UHF generator, tags and reader are expensive.

Any suggestions on how to measure distance in RTL (real-time location system) using RFID?

Comment: RFID tags are not expensive, but they are short range and don't intrinsically support location. What sort of colliding things are you trying to control? You may be better off with an ultrasonic system for short distances (few meters, low speed).

Comment: I want to prevention anti collision between two vehicle

Comment: I want to prevention anti collision between two vehicle .RFID is better option for high speed and long distance .if any idea about tags for  distance measure (RTL system )from moving object than give me information ....                                 thanks for comment

Comment: Why do you say RFID is a better option?

Comment: i don't know more about ultrasonic  system but  ultrasonic system is more expansive compare  to RFID system .i think ultrasonic detection range is high. if any idea about distance measure (RTL system )from moving object please give information ........

Comment: But RFID (a) doesn't inherently measure distance (b) is very short range (too short to apply the brakes) (c) would obviously require a tag on everything that you wanted to avoid colliding with. Some sort of RADAR system might work..

Comment: we are using tag on every object that we want to detect..Active tags will be used by us.

Comment: The irony is that you would do better with truly passive radar targets (conductive or better corner-cube reflectors) since the active electronics in cheap RFID tags lack the time/frequency accuracy of reply needed to support either time-of-flight or doppler measurements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RFID is a terrible method to prevent collision.  Here is why:

LOCATION:  RFID does not detect location.  At best you would have to get multiple receivers/readers and try to do triangulation based on RF signal levels, but that is tricky and error prone.

RANGE:  RFID is inherently short range.  There are versions which are longer range, but these versions actually make triangulating a position more difficult.

SPEED:  RFID is *SLOW*.  The "reader" has to transmit an RF signal long enough to charge up a small cap in the tag (for the APRT version). Only then can the tag respond with its ID.  The bit rate is also relatively slow.  This will reduce the reaction time of your collision avoidance system.

There are versions of RFID that try to improve the range and speed, but these systems are R&D projects and not commercial products.  Even if you could get one, there is no guarantee that it would work for your application.

You could try to roll your own RFID solution that would work for your application, but it is more likely that engineering a proper solution (and not trying to force RFID into this application) would give you better results.

If I were doing this project, I would be looking into those cheap radar units that are currently used in cars for collision avoidance.  They are mainly used in the rear bumper to detect objects when backing up, but they are being used more and more in cars facing forward for break assist and cruise control stuff.